# Fill a sequence containing missing values

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm, missing

**Example data**

```
list = {Missing[], Missing[], 100., 200., Missing[], Missing[], 250., 210., Missing[]};
```

With downloaded data I often have the situation that there are missing values at the beginning and the end of a sequence. In between there are sometimes missing values. But not too many, so that an interpolation is always possible.

The first problem is, that I have to isolate and replace missing start and end values (if any), because otherwise `TemporalData` doesn't work correctly.

```
split = Split[list]
```

{{Missing[], Missing[]}, {100.}, {200.}, {Missing[], Missing[]}, {250.}, {210.}, {Missing[]}}

It follows my terrible solution to temporarily replace them:

```
replace = 
 split /. {x : {___Missing}, t__} :> {Table["m", Length@x], t} /. {h__, x : {___Missing}} :> {h, Table["m", Length@x]}
```

{{"m", "m"}, {100.}, {200.}, {Missing[], Missing[]}, {250.}, {210.}, {"m"}}

Now comes the interpolation,

```
result = 
 TemporalData[Flatten @ replace, 
   MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 1}]["Values"]
```

{0. + "m", 0. + "m", 100., 200., 216.667, 233.333, 250., 210.,
0. + "m"}

which, unfortunately, needs a final clean-up:

```
expected = result /. Plus["m", _] :> Missing[]
```

{Missing[], Missing[], 100., 200., 216.667, 233.333, 250., 210.,
Missing[]}

It is important that the leading and trailing `Missing[]`s are preserved!

Please validate your answer also with

```
list = {150., 165., 100., Missing[], 200., Missing[], Missing[], 250., 210.};
```

I welcome any better alternative (it doesn't need to use `TemporalData`)

Comment: In the `expected` should the second element be different than `Missing[]` or did I misunderstand?

Comment: In the `expected ` the leading and trailing `Missing[]`s must be in the same places as in the beginning `list`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited according to @eldo's comment:

```
specialreplace[list_] := 
 Flatten@SequenceReplace[list, 
   x : {PatternSequence[_Real, ___, _Real]} :> 
    TemporalData[x, 
      MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 1}]["Values"]]

list = {Missing[], Missing[], 100., 200., Missing[], Missing[], 250., 210., Missing[]};
specialreplace[list]
```

> {Missing[], Missing[], 100., 200., 216.667, 233.333, 250., 210., Missing[]}

```
list2 = {150., 165., 100., Missing[], 200., Missing[], Missing[], 250., 210.};
```

> {150., 165., 100., 150., 200., 216.667, 233.333, 250., 210.}

Comment: Wonderful! To save a few keystrokes: `Flatten@SequenceReplace[list, 
  x : {PatternSequence[_Real, ___, _Real]} :> TemporalData[x, ... `

Comment: @eldo Right, thanks! Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Quite ugly, but might inspire someone to come up with a better solution:

```
list //. 
  {pre___, a_?NumericQ, _Missing, m___Missing, b_?NumericQ, post___} :> 
   {pre, a, Rescale[1, {0, Length[{m}] + 2}, {a, b}], m, b, post}
(* {Missing[], Missing[], 100., 200., 216.667, 233.333, 250., 210., Missing[]} *)
```

Comment: In my eyes: not ugly but rather good looking